# Powershell Select Specific Text

Tags: powershell

Hello and thank you for your time.  Here is what I am looking to do.  I have several log files that I need to search through.  I do this by using `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mylogfiles\*.log | Select-String -Pattern 'MyTextHere'`  However, now I want to complicate my life and only select text that is between single quotes in the log files.

Here is a sample of my log file:

This is some sample text in my log file.  It has a lot of garbage that I don't want to see.  However, it has text that I want to find, and if found I would like it to save just the selected text to a CSV file.  I want to copy everything that is between single quotes.  Here comes the text 'Please copy this text that is between the single quotes'

Any idea how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following combines [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) to extract only the phrases of interest (the parts of the line that matched the regex), wraps them in a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a `.Phrase` property and exports the results with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv):

```
Select-String -Path C:\mylogfiles\*.log -AllMatches -Pattern "'.*?'" |
  ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($phrase in $_.Matches.Value) {
      [pscustomobject] @{ Phrase = $phrase.Trim("'") }
    }
  } |
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 result.csv
```

Note: If there can only ever be at most *one* phrase of interest per line, you can omit the `-AllMatches` switch and replace the `ForEach-Object` call with the following [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call, which uses a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```sh
# ... | 
Select-Object -Property @{ Name='Phrase'; Expression={ $_.Matches.Value.Trim("'") } } | 
#  ...
```

Comment: Awesome answer, I was thinking about doing like `([regex]"'.*?'").Matches((Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mylogfiles\*.log | Get-Content -Raw)).Value` but I'm too bad at regex unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon; the regex works, assuming you trim the enclosing `'` afterwards (as I have, because I wanted to keep the regex simple). Note that you could even do `([regex]"'.*?'").Matches((Get-Content -Raw C:\mylogfiles\*.log)).Value.Trim("'")`, but this loads all files into memory in full, up front - and direct use of .NET APIs always adds complexity.

Comment: Ohhhh I totally forgot `Get-Content` can read multiple files, so not used to it! You're right :P still, I didn't know `Select-String` could read files directly, teaching us new stuff everyday, thanks!

Comment: I looked at the code and didn't realize you got rid of `Get-ChildItem` until Santiago pointed it out. Very cool! Didn't know that either (:

Comment: Thank you @mklement0  This worked, and now it showed me that what I thought was between the single quotes, was more than I wanted.  Is there a way to add logic to say only show me what is between the single quotes if there is a specific phrase before it.  For example:  The phrase before the single quotes need to specifically say, for example, I really care what is to come: 'I need this'  I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, you don't see it often, presumably because people are used to combining multiple single-purpose commands in the pipeline, but it does perform better.

Comment: @Lery, you need a positive look-behind assertion,  `(?<=...)`. For instance: `(?<= I really care what is to come: )'.*?'`

Comment: @mklement0 So what would that look like in the completed script above?  I'm not seeing in there so I'm not sure how to put it all together?

Comment: @Lery: Replace `"'.*?'"` with `"(?<= I really care what is to come: )'.*?'"`

Comment: @mklement0 Yup, I did that and it's not working.  The csv just has garbage text in column A row 1.  It's just a few garbled characters.  The completed script looks like this:  Select-String -Path C:\mylogfiles\*.log -AllMatches -Pattern "(?<= I really care what is to come: )'.*?'" |
  ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($phrase in $_.Matches.Value) {
      [pscustomobject] @{ Phrase = $phrase.Trim("'") }
    }
  } |
      Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 result.csv

Comment: @Lery, we know that the command works in principle, and the answer matches the question. Since your follow-up question cannot be resolved in the comments here, please create a _new_ question post, using a [mcve]. Here's a quick demonstration that the look-behind assertion works: `"foo I really care what is to come: 'bar baz'." -match "(?<= I really care what is to come: )'.*?'"; $Matches[0]`

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you again.  I created a new question.